# Como fazer a média de uma lista de tuplas no python?

Tags: python, lista, tupla

Eu estou travado em uma atividade da faculdade que pede para fazer a média das listas de tuplas.

Eu gerei as listas de tuplas através desse código:

```
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
listaTupla = []
for i in range(5):
    var1 = int(input())
    lista1.append(var1)
for j in range(5):
    var2 = int(input())
    lista2.append(var2)

for k,l in zip(lista1, lista2):
    tupla = (k,l)
    listaTupla.append(tupla)

print(listaTupla)
```

O resultado final tem que ser esse.

```
listaDeTuplas=[(14, 93), (23, 84), (0, 5), (4, 43), (5, 1)]
listaDaMedia=[53.5, 53.5, 2.5, 23.5, 3.0]
```

Como posso fazer isso sem importar nada?

Answer (score 2):

No exemplo apresentado na pergunta a função embutida [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) está sendo usada de maneira equivocada:

```python
for k,l in zip(lista1, lista2):
    tupla = (k,l)
    listaTupla.append(tupla)
```

A função `zip()` por si só já itera sobre vários iteráveis em paralelo produzindo tuplas com um item de cada um, sendo desnecessário reiterar seu retorno para produzir uma lista de tuplas. O código acima pode ser simplesmente substituído por:

```python
listaTupla = list(zip(lista1, lista2))
```

Quanto ao problema que gerou sua pergunta, calcular uma lista de médias de uma lista de tuplas, pode ser resolvido de pelo menos três formas.

Uma solução é utilizar a declaração [`for`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) para iterar pela lista de tuplas e com o auxilio da função embutida [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum) a cada iteração somar os elementos de cada tupla dividindo pela quantidade de elementos da  tupla, obtido com o auxilio da função embutida [len()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#len), adicionando o resultado a lista de médias:

```python
lista1 = [14,23,0,4,5]                  #Simplificação do fragmento criando uma lista a partir entrada dum usuário.
lista2 = [93,84,5,43,1]                 #Simplificação do fragmento criando uma lista a partir entrada dum usuário.
listaDaMedia = []                       #Declara a lista que receberá as médias calculadas pelo algoritimo.

listaTupla = list(zip(lista1, lista2))  #Cria uma lista de tuplas geradas a partir da entrada do usuário.

#Para cada tupla t na lista de tuplas...
for t in listaTupla:
  listaDaMedia.append(sum(t)/len(t))    #...soma os elementos da tupla t, divide pelo número de elementos e adiciona ao final da média de médias. 

print(listaTupla)
print(listaDaMedia)
#[(14, 93), (23, 84), (0, 5), (4, 43), (5, 1)]
#[53.5, 53.5, 2.5, 23.5, 3.0]
```

Outra forma seria utilizar [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension) para criar a lista de médias:

```python
lista1 = [14,23,0,4,5]
lista2 = [93,84,5,43,1]

listaTupla = list(zip(lista1, lista2))

#Cria uma lista cujo para cada tupla t na lista de tuplas o elemento resultante será a soma dos elementos da tupla t dividido pelo número de elementos de t.
listaDaMedia=[sum(t)/len(t) for t in listaTupla] 

print(listaTupla)
print(listaDaMedia)
#[(14, 93), (23, 84), (0, 5), (4, 43), (5, 1)]
#[53.5, 53.5, 2.5, 23.5, 3.0]
```

Ainda é possível fazer uso da função embutida [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) para aplicar uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) calculando a média de cada tupla:

```python
lista1 = [14,23,0,4,5]
lista2 = [93,84,5,43,1]

listaTupla = list(zip(lista1, lista2))

#Cria uma lista cujo a cada elemento na lista de tuplas será aplicada uma função que a recebe a tupla como como argumento pelo parâmetro t e calcula soma os elementos de t e divide pelo número de elementos de t, onde o retorno da função e o elemento resultante.
listaDaMedia= list(map(lambda t: sum(t)/len(t), listaTupla))

print(listaTupla)
print(listaDaMedia)
#[(14, 93), (23, 84), (0, 5), (4, 43), (5, 1)]
#[53.5, 53.5, 2.5, 23.5, 3.0]
```

Comment: Apenas respondi pois a outra resposta(já devidamente removida) além de não atender ao problema proposto ensinava o uso errado da linguagem.